# Determine positive integer solutions to $ a^b+1=(a+1)^c$

Tags: number-theory

Determine all positive integer solutions to the equation

$$ a^b+1=(a+1)^c$$

(Source : Taiwan MO 1999)

My work, not using Zsigmondy's theorem :

Let $p$ be prime such that $p\mid a+1$.

By LTE, $\;v_p(a^b+1)= v_p(a+1)+v_p(b)=v_p(a+1)c$

we get $v_p(b)=v_p(a+1)(c-1)$ so $b\geq p^{c-1}$

and $a^{p^{c-1}}+1 \leq (a+1)^c \leq (2a)^c$   ---[1]

For $a=1$, we have $c=1, b \in \mathbb{N}$, so $(a,b,c)= (1,n,1), \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

For $a>1$,

if $c=1$, we have $b=1, a \in \mathbb{N}$, so $(a,b,c)= (n,1,1), \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

if $c=2$, then $b>2$, if $b=3$ we have $a=2$, so $(a,b,c)= (2,3,2)$, and if $b>3$, this contradicts $a^b+1=(a+1)^2$

if $c=3$, then $b>3$, since $(a+1)^3 \geq a^4+1$ so $a$ can only be $2$ and $2^b+1=27$, contradiction.

if $c>3$, we have $p^{c-1} \geq 2^{c-1} \geq 2c$, so $p^{c-1}-c \geq c$

since $a>1$, so $a^{p^{c-1}-c} \geq 2^c\;$,i.e., $\;a^{p^{c-1}} \geq 2^ca^c$

then $a^{p^{c-1}}+1 > a^{p^{c-1}} \geq (2a)^c$, contradicts [1]

Answer : $(a,b,c)= (1,n,1), (n,1,1), (2,3,2), \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

P.S. I don't know the answer of this problem, please help me check my answer.

Comment: What is "LTE" ?

Comment: @Peter. Please see here, http://s3.amazonaws.com/aops-cdn.artofproblemsolving.com/resources/articles/lifting-the-exponent.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Catalan's conjecture(actually theorem,but the name stuck) the only consecutive powers of integer bigger than $1$ are $2^3,3^2$,

And substituting for $b=1$ and solving, doing the same for $c=1$ and solving, should be enough to conclude the proof.

Comment: For b = 1, (a,b,c)= (n,1,1). For c = 1, (a,b,c)= (1,n,1). And for b, c > 1, (a,b,c)= (2,3,2). I think this is the complete set of answers, right ?

Comment: Correct, it's obvious from Catalan's conjecture that these are the only integer solutions.

Comment: @carat Didn't you want to know whether your proof is correct ?

Comment: @Peter, Yes, can someone please check the validity of my work ?